# How to map transactions to each other based on FIFO logic in SQL

Tags: sql, pyspark

I am writing a pySpark application to calculate my capital gains tax.
I created a transactions table that looks like the one in the sample (I filtered out one specific stock since it illustrates the problem I want to solve.

[image: Data sample]

I would like to map Buy transactions to Sell transactions in a FIFO manner.

As you can see, there are 4 buy transactions with different quantities and prices. The first sell transaction (-150) should correspond to the Buy transaction of 100 shares on 2020-06-18 and half of the second Buy transaction (50 out of 100 shares bought at 2020-06-29).
The second sell transaction (-50) should map to the remaining 50 shares bought at 2020-06-29.

Could you help me design a SQL query (or pySpark code) to calculate the mapping?
I would imagine it should look something like:

[image: Result table]